# Can SQLite REPLACE multiple rows and ignore failed ones

Tags: sql, sqlite

There is a users table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "users" (
  "id" bigint PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  "name" text NOT NULL,
  "gender" integer NOT NULL
);
```

And I execute the sql as follows:

1、Fails with `NOT NULL constraint failed: users.name`

```
insert into users(id, name, gender) values (1, 'Jack', 1), (2, Null, 1), (3, 'Mary', 0);
```

2、Insert items 1 and 3 successfully

```
insert or ignore into users(id, name, gender) values (1, 'Jack', 1), (2, Null, 1), (3, 'Mary', 0);
```

3、Also fails with `NOT NULL constraint failed: users.name`

```
replace into users(id, name, gender) values (1, 'Jack', 1), (2, Null, 1), (3, 'Mary', 0);
```

I want execute replace if there duplicated row in my table, and if one item fails to meet the constraint, other items can be inserted or replaced successfully. But  `REPLACE OR IGNORE` is not supported. Is there other way to do this？

Comment: Perhaps you can go with 2 SQL statements like:

`replace into users (id, name, gender) values (1, 'Jack', 1), ... where id in (select id from users);`

`insert into users (id, name, gender) ... where id not in (select id from users);`

Untested, but you get the idea,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REPLACE is an alias for [INSERT OR REPLACE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html), and you can specify only one [conflict resolution algorithm](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html).

There is no way to do this with a single statement.
You have to insert the rows one by one, and to manually check for most of the possible constraint violations.